Determining Minimum Shadow Circumference for Group of People Standing Beneath a Tree
"Suppose there's a tree located at coordinates (0, 0). Its shadow is circular because the sun is directly overhead. A group of people is standing in the shadow, and their coordinates are provided. What should be the minimum circumference of the tree's shadow be to ensure all these people are within its shade?" Everyone trusts you because you are very intelligent. Now solve the problem given by the tree.
-> No two or more persons stand at the same coordinates.
PI = 2*acos(0.0)
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define Pi 3.14159265358979323846

double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    double dist=((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
    return dist;
}
void solve()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    double mxd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        double x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        double dist = distance(0, 0, x, y);
        mxd = max(mxd, dist);
    }
    mxd=sqrt(mxd);
    double ans = 2 * Pi * mxd;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << ans << endl;
}

signed main()
{
    fast;
    int t;  cin>>t;
    for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        //cout<<"i :"<<i<<endl;
        solve(); //return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

i write this code but jujdge shows tle at test case 11. I think it is for calculating sqrt of radius. but i don't know how to solve it . help me .
first i calculate the maximum ditance from (0,0) to (x,y) by equation (x^2+y^2=r^2) and then calculate the circumference =2Pir; my code time complexity is O(T*sqrt(10^8)); cause max distance =(0+10^4)^2+(0+10^4)^2; how to make it more optimized way.

Please show your code and format your question properly using code formatting. BTW, you don't need to get sqrt every time, calculate maxinum of squared distance.

@MBo i have added my code

OK, I don't see much faster way. Possible approach to get some gain - work in  integers (until sqrt) if provided coordinates are ints (long integer for squared dist)
